# What is the smallest and largest $|z|$ that makes $|a+z|+|a-z|=2|c|$ complex analysis By Lars Ahlfors 1.1.5.4

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

In Complex analysis by  Lars Ahlfors 1.1.5.4

> 4. Show that there are complex numbers $z$ satisfying
>    $|z - a| + |z + a| = 2|c|$
>    if and only if $|a| \le |c|$- If this condition is fulfilled, what are the smallest
>    and largest values of |z|?

The first two questions are easy if $|c|>|a|$, $z=\frac{|c|a}{|a|}$ will make this equality $|a|(\left|\frac{|c|-|a|}{|a|}\right| + \left|\frac{|c|-|a|}{|a|}\right|)=2|c| $

and if $|z - a| + |z + a| = 2|c|$ then $|a|< |c|$ by triangle inequality

the last two questions were very challenging to me and I couldn't find an answer.

I want to ask specifically for an algebraic approach as the geometric interpretation of the complex number is in the next part of this chapter so the author had some proof that work without representing complex numbers in the complex plane

Comment: One special case is when $a$  is real and $a > 0$  The picture of the ellipse should be familiar in this case. Tell you what, why don't you carefully draw a picture with $a=3$  and $c = 3 + 4 i$

Comment: printable graph paper. https://print-graph-paper.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
 2 |z| = | (z-a)+(z+a)| \le |z-a| + |z+a| = 2|c|  \, ,
$$
so that $ \boxed{|z| \le |c|}$. Equality holds if $z-a$ and $z+a$ are real non-negative multiples of each other, that is for
$$
 z = \pm |c|\frac{a}{|a|}  \, .
$$

For the other direction we can use the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):
$$
\begin{align}
 4 |c|^2 &= |z-a|^2 + |z+a|^2 + 2 |z-a| \cdot |z+a| \\
 &= 2 |z|^2 + 2 |a|^2 + 2 |z^2-a^2| \\
 &\le 2 |z|^2+ 2 |a|^2 + 2 |z|^2 + 2 |a|^2 \\
 &= 4 (|z|^2 + |a|^2) \, ,
\end{align}
$$
so that $\boxed{|z| \ge \sqrt{|c|^2 - |a|^2}}$. Equality holds if $|z^2-a^2| = |z|^2 + |a|^2$, that is if $z^2$ and $-a^2$ are real non-negative multiples of each other, i.e. for
$$
 z = \pm i \sqrt{|c|^2-|a|^2}\frac{a}{|a|} \, .
$$

Comment: so what is the largest value of $z$

Comment: $|z| = |c|$ is the largest possible value, and $|z| = \sqrt{|c|^2 - |a|^2}$ is the smallest possible value.